# Running protractor against specific database

Tags: database, angularjs, protractor

I'm running a Ruby on Rails app using AngularJS for our customer facing pages, and want to know how to run my protractor tests against a specific database, such as test. For example, when testing with Rspec it automatically runs against the test database(as opposed to my production or development or staging databases)

Comment: This is not something that needs to be solved on protractor's side. protractor is an end-to-end testing framework automating browsers.

Comment: @alecxe in my case for example, to carry out a test with a protractor I need to connect to the orable db to find data. What is the correct way to do it ? thx

Answer (score 1):

I use this gem which helps you run protractor tests on the test database.

https://github.com/tyronewilson/protractor-rails